# why does this loop print all values between 10-20? I want it to print the values that are divisible by 5

Tags: java, while-loop

```
int z=10;
int x=5;
boolean t= ((z % x) == 0);
while ( t && (z < 21))
       {
           s +=String.format("%8d", z)+this.mp.outstandingAfter(z, "%16.0f");
           s+= "\n\n";
           z++;
       }
```

I want it to print the 10th, 15th, and 20th value but it's printing all values between 10-20. I can't understand why?

Comment: `t` never changes.

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Your `t` never changes and it really is not necessarily, since you could just check if the condition is true in each iteration.

```
int z=10;
int x=5;
while (z < 21) {
    if((z % x) == 0) {
        s +=String.format("%8d", z)+this.mp.outstandingAfter(z, "%16.0f");
        s += "\n\n";
    }
    z++;
}
```

Comment: That's not going to work how he wants it, because as soon as t becomes false (z=11) the loop will stop. So it will stop after finding the first number that isn't divisible by 5 and only print out `10`. `t` cannot be part of the while condition. It must be checked with an extra if statement inside the loop.

Comment: You are right. In fact, `t` is no even needed. All he needs to do is check when z % x == 0, before printing.

Comment: Why have `x` at all?

Comment: Well, in this case it is not needed, but let's say he wants to modify the rule and now he want all numbers divisible by 4. X makes a bit more sense there, but for this example, is clear that x is not even needed, if he will never need that value anymore.

Comment: It works; thank you so much!

Comment: I am glad it worked! If you don't mind, please check my answer as correct :)